# how to uninstall steam from my ubuntu

Tags: uninstall, games, steam

How can I uninstall steam from my ubuntu? I've tried the terminal step of sudo apt-get remove steam, but it tells me that it doesn't exist, and it does exist, I can see it, please help

Comment: You need to uninstall in the reverse procedure to how you installed it.  `sudo apt-get remove steam` would work if you used `sudo apt-get install steam` (or `dpkg -i` & like apt tools). If you `dpkg -l |grep steam` do you get a list of installed packages with `steam` in their name? (which can be removed by `apt` tools).  If you installed in another way, you need to remove it likewise using the reverse of install-method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On my system the package is `steam-launcher` (I installed it from the Steam repos).

See if that's what you have by issuing `apt policy steam-launcher` in a terminal.  If so, that's what you should uninstall.